# Lotus Notes get value from rich text to a text field

Tags: lotus-notes, abstract, richtext

I'm following this guide (look under "Views" section): 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Working_with_IBM_Lotus_Notes_rich_text_fields

But I can't get/retrieve the value in my view. I created a new column, added the variable "HiddenUserField" and tried to use @Abstract as described in the guide. Also I tried @Text, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create this hidden field in your form, not in view. Use the formula

```
@Abstract([TextOnly]; 1000; ""; "ProposedRes")
```

After you added it to your form you have to recalculate all documents so that this hidden field gets filled. As an alternative you could write an agent which sets the hidden field using @Abstract in all documents.

Comment: Yes I have created "HiddenUserField" in the form, next to the rich text field called "ProposedRes".
I was thinking that either;
@Abstract( [TextOnly] ; 64000 ; "" ; "$ProposedRes" )
or
@Text(ProposedRes) 
would do the trick? Tried with and witout ' " " ' and without the variable sign $. Lotus Notes is new to me as you might have guessed.

Comment: Use `@Abstract( [TextOnly] ; ... )` but only with 1000 chars. 64000 is too much as of 64K restrictions in Notes. And, don't forget to recalculate documents.

Comment: Still nothing, but thanks. @Abstract([TextOnly]; 1000; ""; "$ProposedRes") with and without $ and "" doesn't give any results. F9 for recalculate?

Comment: Create an agent with formula `@Command([ToolsRefreshAllDocs])`or `@Command([ToolsRefreshSelectedDocs])` to recalculate all field or better and with better performance `FIELD HiddenUserField := @Abstract([TextOnly]; 1000; ""; "ProposedRes")`

Comment: Creating a agent, saving and going back to the View, selecting all documents and running the agent with the code: FIELD HiddenUserField := @Abstract([TextOnly]; 1000; ""; "ProposedRes") did it! Thank you Knut